# Way to include a quick adding method to a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, uitextfield

I would need to add a textfield and a button to be shown over a tableview or to pull down the tableview and show a textfield and a button above the tableview. The purpose of the textfield and button should  be to allow the user to add a core data object to the store, with limited attributes (only one, but later the user could open an edit view controller to add more attributes values), just as a quick add method, all of this should be fired by a bar button item. I have seen something similar on other apps.
Any idea about this is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bar button item to trigger a method which creates and shows a `UIAlertView`. This can be configured with a single text label (`alertViewStyle` as `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`) and buttons of your choice. Set your controller as the delegate and you have everything you need.